# Convert SQL QUERY to Django

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, django-queryset

I have the next query in Postgres:

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, a.code,
(SELECT coalesce((SELECT MAX(value) FROM financials WHERE client_key=a.id AND year=2016), 0) AS ca_vlr_n)
FROM clients a
```

I want to translate it into Django, but I do not know how to deal with that Coalesce. I've done this:

```
queryset = Client.objects.values('name', 'code').annotate(ca_vlr_n=Coalesce(Max('financial__value'), V(0)))
```

But I do not know how to put the condition for year.

My model is:

```
class Client(models.Model):
    name                = models.CharField(help_text="Client's Name", max_length=128, unique=True)
    code                = models.CharField(help_text="Client's CUI", max_length=50)

class Financial(models.Model):
    year                = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    client              = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    value               = models.BigIntegerField()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `Coalesce` with `Case`

```
queryset = Client.objects.filter(financial__year=2016, ).values('name', 'code').annotate(
    ca_vlr_n=Case(
        When(financial__year=2016, then=Max('financial__value')),
        output_field=BigIntegerField(), default=V(0)
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks, but is is not ok. It returns me more than I need. It returns me all financials years for all my clients

Comment: It sa an exception: django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'financial_set' into field.

Comment: @tatulea do you have `related_name` in `client = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE)`?

Comment: No, the model is just above

Comment: @tatulea what about using `financial` instead of `financial_set`?

Comment: It returns me 1200 clients, but I have 1600 clients in my database. I do not guarantee that all of this clients have a value for year 2016 in financial table